# PHP and Angular JS resource post

Tags: php, angularjs, angular-resource

How will I receive my post data comes from angular resource to php?

**Angular controller:**

```
myApp.controller('myController', ['$scope', 'USER', function($scope, USER) {

$scope.addItem = function () {
    USER.save($scope.item, function () {
        $scope.items.push($scope.item);
        console.log($scope.item);
    });
};

}]);
```

**HTML Form:**

```
<div ng-app="myApp">
<form method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data" ng-controller="myController">
  <label>Email</label>
  <input type="text" name="txtEmail" ng-model="item.txtEmail" />
  <label>Fullname</label>
  <input type="text" name="txtFullname" ng-model="item.txtFullname" />
  <button type="button" ng-click="addItem()" name="btnSubmit">
    Add Data
  </button>
</form>
</div>
```

**PHP:**

```
public function addUser(){
    $txtEmail = $_POST['txtEmail'];
    $txtFullname = $_POST['txtFullname'];


    if(isset($_POST['btnSubmit'])):
        $query = $this->sql->prepare('INSERT INTO tbl_users (id, fullname, email) VALUES (NULL, :fullname, :email)');
        $query->execute(array(':fullname' => $txtFullname, ':email' => $txtEmail));
    endif;
}
```

**Screenshot:**

[image]

In my given screenshot, how will my php function received the output of angular resource?

Comment: You have to send ajax call...

Answer (score 0):

You need to send the ajax call to the php page you want to read the data . In the angular controller 
(you need to include $http in the app controller)

```
USER.save($scope.item, function () {
   $http.post('/poster.php',{item:$scope.item})
                   .then(function(result) {
                        console.log( result.data) ; // the response from server
                    });
```

In your **poster.php** file (or controller), you need to check for the POST variables as you normally do and send back the response.

```
print_r($_POST['item']);
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is the answer:
I can't considered angular post as an regular php post:
http://codeforgeek.com/2014/07/angular-post-request-php/